# How do I write a number larger than u8 to a pointer?

Tags: rust

Doing some allocation with the `alloc` crate and I have stumbled upon a problem. As alloc returns a u8 pointer, I'm not able to write integers larger than 255 to that address. How would I fix that?

```rust
let ps = alloc(Layout::from_size_align(4096, 8).unwrap());
ps.write(399); // this line gives out of range error
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast pointer to needed type. Alloc is low level, it works with just "memory" so uses u8 because it is most close to meaning of "raw bytes".

```rust
let ps = alloc(Layout::from_size_align(4096, 8).unwrap());
let ps = ps as *mut MyTargetType;

// Use ps here
// ....

let ps = ps as *mut u8;
dealloc(ps, Layout::from_size_align(4096, 8).unwrap());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by casting it to another pointer type, e.g. `*mut u32`. You can do that by calling [`cast()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.cast-1), i.e. `ps.cast::<u32>()`, which is the same as `ps as *mut u32`. Then after that you can [`write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.write) or assign to the reinterpreted pointer.

```rust
let layout = Layout::from_size_align(4096, 8).unwrap();
let ps = alloc(layout);

ps.cast::<u32>().write(399);
assert_eq!(*ps.cast::<u32>(), 399);

*ps.cast::<u32>() = 399;
assert_eq!(*ps.cast::<u32>(), 399);

*(ps as *mut u32) = 399;
assert_eq!(*(ps as *const u32), 399);

dealloc(ps, layout);
```